# Javascript toFixed, toString replacing currency failing

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following snippet which works great with the following currency format: 249.00 however i am placing on a site that uses euros and the pricing is in a different format which is 249,00 however when calculating it is going crazy and making the totaling 29.900,00

Does anyone know what changes i need to make in order to work with the new currency change?

```
var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
total = total.replace(/\.|\,/g,''); // remove thousand , and decimal .
total = Shopify.formatMoney(total, '{{ shop.money_format }}');
$('.cart-finalTotal span').html(total);
```

FULL CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide initial values that need updating
  $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
  // get current delivery rate
  $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
  // set a timeout and get total and shipping that was generated and add together for nnew total
  setTimeout(function() {
    // get cart sub-total
    var a = $(".cart-total span").html().replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, "");

    if ($("#estimated-shipping em").text() == "FREE") {
      var b = "0.00";
      var isFree = "true";
    } else {
      var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, ""));
    }
    if(isFree == "true") {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("{{ 'cart.shipping_estimator.free' | t }}");
    } else {
      var shopifyShipping = b.toFixed(2);
      shopifyShipping = shopifyShipping.replace(/\.|\,/g,''); // remove thousand , and decimal .
      shopifyShipping = Shopify.formatMoney(shopifyShipping, '{{ shop.money_format }}');
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html(shopifyShipping);
    }

    // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
    // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
    var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
    total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    total = total.replace(/\.|\,/g,''); // remove thousand , and decimal .
    total = Shopify.formatMoney(total, '{{ shop.money_format }}');
    $('.cart-finalTotal span').html(total);

    // show new values
    $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();

    //console.log('{{ 'cart.shipping_estimator.free' | t }}');
  }, 2000);
  $(".item-quantity input").on("change", function() {
    document.location.href = location.href
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to replace the comma with a dot, _before_ you pass that value to parseFloat.

Comment: Comma in this part? .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."); if so i tried, but did not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: No, in the part where you try to parse the value `249,00` into a float.

Comment: Sorry little new to JS to be honest, i have added the full source..

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I know a simple solution but for any notice out there that this might help just adding to the replace helped

```
.replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, "");
```

to

```
.replace(/[^0-9.,]/gi, "");
```